# Export Tensorflow experiment model with savedmodel

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Please how  can I save this model using [TensorFlow SaveModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model).

```
train_steps = int(0.5 + (1.0 * num_epochs * nusers) / batch_size)
    steps_in_epoch = int(0.5 + nusers / batch_size)
    print("Will train for {} steps, evaluating once every {} steps".format(train_steps, steps_in_epoch))
    def experiment_fn(output_dir):
        return tf.contrib.learn.Experiment(
            tf.contrib.factorization.WALSMatrixFactorization(
                num_rows = nusers, 
                num_cols = nitems,
                embedding_dimension = n_embeds,
                model_dir = output_dir),
            train_input_fn = read_dataset(tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN, input_path,batch_size, nitems, nusers, num_epochs,n_embeds, output_dir),
            eval_input_fn = read_dataset(tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL, input_path, batch_size, nitems, nusers, num_epochs, n_embeds, output_dir),
            train_steps = train_steps,
            eval_steps = 1,
            min_eval_frequency = steps_in_epoch,
            export_strategies = tf.contrib.learn.utils.saved_model_export_utils.make_export_strategy(serving_input_fn = create_serving_input_fn(nitems, nusers))
        )
```

I have tried replacing the export_strategies with  `export_strategies=tf.export_saved_model(output_dir, serving_input_fn = create_serving_input_fn(nitems, nusers))` and it returns the following error message

`AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'export_saved_model`

Also tried `export_strategies=tf.saved_model(output_dir, serving_input_fn = create_serving_input_fn(nitems, nusers))`

`TypeError: 'DeprecationWrapper' object is not callable`

Answer (score 0):

The SavedModel format is another way to serialize models. Models saved in this format can be restored using [tf.keras.models.load_model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model) and are compatible with TensorFlow Serving. The SavedModel guide goes into detail about how to serve/inspect the [SavedModel](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model).
The below code illustrates the steps to save and restore the model.

```
# Create and train a new model instance.
model = create_model()
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

# Save the entire model as a SavedModel.
!mkdir -p saved_model
model.save('saved_model/my_model')

# my_model directory
ls saved_model

# Contains an assets folder, saved_model.pb, and variables folder.
ls saved_model/my_model

# Reload a fresh Keras model from the saved model:
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model/my_model')
```